# Permutations and Combinations Product of Digits SIMPLE 2 MARKER

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question: Pairs of numbers from the list $1,2,3,4,...,n$ are chosen and their product is calculated. The same number may be chosen twice (e.g. $3\cdot3=9$) but the order of the selection does not matter (e.g. $3\cdot2$ and $2\cdot3$ are considered the same pair)

Show that there are $$ {n^2 + n}\over 2 $$ ways that the pairs may be chosen.

What I have done:
I thought all you need to do is: $nC1 \cdot nC1$ divided by $2$ to remove repetition or something and then you add $nC2$

*Note*: Please help me in a simple way. This is only an Australian Year 12 question so thanks.

Comment: A simple approach: Find the number of ways if the numbers were different.  Add this to the number of ways if the numbers were the same.  A more complicated but easily generalizable approach: [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: I tried nC2 x 2! which is choosing 2 different numbers and then ordering them

Comment: Then to add to that i thought nC1 x 1C1 because repeating the same number? But theres something wrong in that

Comment: "*I tried nC2 x 2! which is choosing 2 different numbers and then ordering them*"  Why multiply by $2!$?  Why order them?  We specifically wanted order *not* to matter.  It should just be $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose two different numbers with order not mattering.  "*Then to add to that I thought nC1 x 1C1...*" Why bother including the $\times \binom{1}{1}$ bit when writing this?  Its not wrong, but unnecessary.  Just call it $n$ and be done with it.  It takes one character as opposed to seven (*not including whitespace*).  Now... what is $\binom{n}{2}+n$?  Is it familiar?

Comment: I will point out that in your original post you said "*nC1 x nC1 divided by 2*" which you should notice for odd values of $n$ will not result in an integer and as such could not possibly have been the answer to a counting question.  Sanity checks like that are often useful to quickly spot if an answer is incorrect.